# Constantly refreshing/receiving output <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I have this div on my site

```html
<div class="col-sm-4"  >
  <div id="RealTimeClose" class="nest">
    <div class="title-alt">
      <h6>
        <span class="fontawesome-resize-horizontal"></span>&nbsp;Deposit Feed</h6>
      <div class="titleClose">
        <a class="gone" href="#RealTimeClose">
          <span class="entypo-cancel"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="titleToggle">
        <a class="nav-toggle-alt" href="#RealTime">
          <span class="entypo-up-open"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="RealTime" style="min-height:296px;padding-top:20px;" class="body-nest">
      <?php include('table1.php'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And Im trying to get it to continously load data from table1.php after like 1 second intervals... how can i go about doing this

Comment: you can use setinterval

Comment: could i have an example including my script on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    function reloadTable(){
        $.get( "table1.php", function( data ) {
            $( "#RealTime" ).html( data );
        });
    }
reload = setInterval(reloadTable, 1000);
});
```

Comment: then do i have to load that function anywhere? where in particular

Comment: that code is designed to be added to the HTML as is. setInterval is designed to take 2 parameters; the function to call, and the number of milliseconds between each call to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Uing JQuery / AJAX will solve your problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New document</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- This is for including the JQuery, found at https://jquery.com -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            });
            var Interval = setInterval(function(){
                $("#users").load("table1.php"); // $("#users") is a selector to select the id "users", and the load function explains itself...
            }, 1000/*Refresh rate : currently one second*/);
        </script>
        <p>Users found: </p>
        <div id="users">Users found her</div>
    </body>
</html>
```